# TL431 as negative voltage reference

Tags: tl431

Im building a LM317 based power supply and the output range must be 0.3V-21V. I've used a 2 diodes in series and a resistor supplied by a negative voltage and take the node between resistor and diode to be a negative reference to be fed to the adjust pin of LM317 to reduce its reference voltage. Now, I found other people saying TL431 is much better reference voltage but I dont know how to reduce its reference voltage. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I found other people saying TL431 is much better reference
>   voltage but I dont know how to reduce its reference voltage

You can't reduce the reference voltage - it is fixed at 2.5 volts but you can certainly use it as a

> negative voltage reference

[image]